How to get the full HTML and CSS (computed styles) of a component in Angular with ViewChild?
I have a component in Angular, and I need to extract the full HTML content along with the computed CSS styles of a specific element using ViewChild. I'm currently able to get the HTML content using:
@ViewChild('mySelector', { static: false }) mySelector!: ElementRef;
const htmlContent = this.mySelector?.nativeElement?.innerHTML;

the html code is missing some css styles
link here is the link to stackblitz

could you replicate your issue on a stackblitz and update on the question

@NarenMurali on a stackblitz?? No, here on Stack Overflow, which has facilities to do the same thing.

@Pointy SO editor does not provide the facility to create working angular code

Fair point, though I don't think this has much to do with Angular specifically; the OP is going to have to create (or find) a tool to perform .getComputedStyle() on each element of a DOM subtree.

link here is the link to stackblitz

added solution and stackblitz  link can please check

solved my issue thank you so much  ?

I think your issue might be a timing one with the lifecycle. You were using a ngOnInit, however the view has not loaded at this point in the lifecycle. Im not sure what it is you are looking for, so its hard to verify, but ngAfterViewInit might be what you need.
stackblitz
